# Finding a normal looking kitchen faucet with side spray and filter

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture

My current kitchen faucet is apparently cheap junk, installed by a previous owner of contractor who did not give a damn. It now needs replacement because it is leaking. Apparently, the reason it is leaking is that the Brita faucet filter I have had on it has added enough back pressure to wreck it's cheap junkness.

When I went shopping I was very disappointed in the available selection. All the faucets available look like goofy, stupid, designer things. I want it to look like a freaking **faucet**. I also want to have a side spray,or at least be compatible with added side sprays.

I'd like to have the filter built in, so I know it won't wreck the new faucet, but I will settle for having a normal screw-on aerator so I can use my existing one.

Oh, it also has to not be cheap junk.

Where can I find such a thing?

EDIT:
This is what I mean by normal looking. Single lever, straight diagonal spout.

[image]

Comment: Any answer to this would be a completely subjective answer to a shopping question. Double off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try at a local hardware store as opposed to going off to the big chain box stores. My local hardware store has a few catalogs that show many styles of faucets for kitchen sinks - including a lot of "normal" looking ones.

There are also a number of online sites including www.faucet.com although I have not always been convinced that their prices are all that great.